# Reading a column that contains a JSON string from BigQuery using Spark Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, google-bigquery, apache-spark-sql

I have a table in BigQuery that I am reading from using spark java. However when I try and access a columns nested JSON values I am unable to using from_json.

The column 'sender' has this structure:

```
{"UserInfo":{"CorporateEmailAddress":"email@gmail.com","UUID":32341983,"FirstName":"John","FirmNumber":678,"PersonalEmailAddress":"email@gmail.com","LastName":"Doe","AccountName":"AccountName","AccountNumber":12345}}
```

And I create the Nested struct types like below:

```
StructType userInfo = new StructType();
    userInfo.add("CorporateEmailAddress", DataTypes.StringType, false);
    userInfo.add("UUID", DataTypes.IntegerType, false);
    userInfo.add("FirstName", DataTypes.StringType, false);
    userInfo.add("FirmNumber", DataTypes.IntegerType, false);
    userInfo.add("PersonalEmailAddress", DataTypes.StringType, false);
    userInfo.add("LastName", DataTypes.StringType, false);
    userInfo.add("AccountName", DataTypes.StringType, false);
    userInfo.add("AccountNumber", DataTypes.IntegerType, false);

    StructType schema = new StructType();
    schema = schema.add("UserInfo", userInfo, false);
```

Then using spark I use withColumn and from_json using my schema to create a column in which I can access the nested fields in the JSON string.

```
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
            .appName("spark-bigquery-pipeline")
            .getOrCreate();

    Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().format("bigquery")
            .option("table", "table-email-data").load();

   Dataset<Row> jsonColumnDataset = df.withColumn("jsonCol",functions.from_json(df.col("sender"), schema));
    jsonColumnDataset.printSchema();

    jsonColumnDataset.select("jsonCol").show();
```

However on running this code my output is:

```
  +-------+
|jsonCol|
+-------+
|   {{}}|
|   {{}}|
|   {{}}|
|   {{}}|
|   {{}}|
|   {{}}|
|   {{}}|
|   {{}}|
|   {{}}|
|   {{}}|
```

So it looks like I am not correctly parsing the JSON and creating a blank column?

EDIT: And here is the output of the jsonColumnDataset.printSchema();

```
  root
 |-- message_ID: string (nullable = false)
 |-- msg_time: string (nullable = false)
 |-- msg_time_UTC: string (nullable = false)
 |-- msg_lang: string (nullable = false)
 |-- subject: string (nullable = false)
 |-- msg_body: string (nullable = false)
 |-- disc_ref: string (nullable = true)
 |-- greeting: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sender: string (nullable = false)
 |-- recipient: string (nullable = false)
 |-- attachment: string (nullable = true)
 |-- jsonCol: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- UserInfo: struct (nullable = true)
```

Can anyone see what might be wrong with my approach?

Comment: Can you please show the output of `jsonColumnDataset.printSchema();` ?

Comment: @shubham I've added that output in an edit on my original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue probably lies in your created schema structure.

You didn't create all json fields as `StructField`.

### Created schema

```
StructType userInfo = new StructType(new StructField[] {
     new StructField("CorporateEmailAddress", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()),
     new StructField("UUID", DataTypes.IntegerType, false, Metadata.empty()),
     new StructField("FirstName", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()),
     new StructField("FirmNumber", DataTypes.IntegerType, false, Metadata.empty()),
     new StructField("PersonalEmailAddress", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()),
     new StructField("LastName", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()),
     new StructField("AccountName", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()),
     new StructField("AccountNumber", DataTypes.IntegerType, false, Metadata.empty())
 }
);
```

```
StructType schema = new StructType();
schema = schema.add(new StructField("UserInfo", userInfo, false, Metadata.empty()));
```

### Printed the data

```
Dataset<Row> jsonColumnDataset = customerDF.withColumn("jsonCol", functions.from_json(customerDF.col("sender"), schema));

jsonColumnDataset.select("jsonCol").show(false);
```

### Output

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|jsonCol                                                                    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[email@gmail.com,32341983,John,678,email@gmail.com,Doe,AccountName,12345]]|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

### Print new Schema

```
jsonColumnDataset.printSchema();
root
 |-- sender: string (nullable = true)
 |-- jsonCol: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- UserInfo: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- CorporateEmailAddress: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- UUID: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- FirstName: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- FirmNumber: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- PersonalEmailAddress: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- LastName: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- AccountName: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- AccountNumber: integer (nullable = false)
```

### Access Individual Fields from newly added json column

```
jsonColumnDataset.select("jsonCol.UserInfo.CorporateEmailAddress").show(false);
jsonColumnDataset.select("jsonCol.UserInfo.UUID").show(false);
```

##### Output

```
|CorporateEmailAddress|
+---------------------+
|email@gmail.com      |
+---------------------+

+--------+
|UUID    |
+--------+
|32341983|
+--------+
```

Comment: I tried this approach and worked as you showed, it got me further than before however now I'm trying to get specifically the value of CorporateEmailAddress. I thought it would be as simple as doing a `jsonColumnDataset.select("jsonCol.CorporateEmailAddress").show(false)` however that gives me the error `No such struct field CorporateEmailAddress in UserInfo` .. any ideas what I'm missing?